# SqlException encountered while accessing the target data source

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerbi-datasource, data-gateway, powerbi-datagateway

> Unable to create data source.The analysis request operation is timed out before it was completed.

> Details: Gd Server 80: Received error payload from gateway service with ID 67805: SqlException encountered while accessing the target data source

> Status Code: 400

I am trying to setup Data Gateway on my On Premises Windows Server with SQL Server 2014 installed running on Port 9003

The Latest Data Gateway installed (downloaded 14th Sep 2022) in standard mode is running fine as we can see it appearing on Power BI Service

In Power BI Desktop the query timeout is set to 200 and the data is only a few KBs

Now, whenever we try to add credentials using "Basic" method for data source and provide the respective database's credentials, it gives us below error (image attached) - Not sure exactly why it happening but below 2 things to be noted

- If we give incorrect password it returns the same error - means the
  error is returned even before the authentication
- If we give incorrect server IP then it returns a different error "a
  network related or instance specific error occurred..." - means the
  PBi Service is able to access the server when given the correct
  IP,port

I am able to connect the same IP,Port through Power BI Desktop and SSMS

[image]

Comment: Troubleshooting 1) Look at the Gateway Logs  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-onprem-tshoot 2) Look at the SQL Logs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/view-the-sql-server-error-log-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16 3) Retry while running Profiler  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved - It was actually a Network Issue pertains to NAT Loopback.

The network I have been working on does not support NAT Loopback - Data Gateway and SQL Server was installed on same network servers and I have been trying to connect the Data Gateway with SQL Server using Public IP rather than local IP - As I mentioned NAT Loopback was not enabled therefore Data Gateway was not able to access the SQL Server with Public IP. When it was setup using local IP, it worked

Moreover, It is working with Personal Gateway too

[image]